# Who is right? - SQL Rollback Question

Tags: sql, rollback

a few minutes ago I had a discussion with my boss and want now more meanings, if I am wrong or he is.

Following problem is given:
After a fast change from a colleague a stored procedure went wrong.
(I think for the theory here is no more information requiered)

We decide to provide the correct version in an Update Script:

IF EXIST PROCEDURE X ....
DROP PROCEDURE X ....
CREATE PROCEDURE X ....

For the DBO that the correcture will be execute, we must (should) prepare an rollback mechanism. My Boss comes to me and ask me for preparing an rollback script. I tell him, that we don't have one: Because when the main script failed, there is no option. It went now completly wrong, we can't rollback to the wrong one. It's senseless.

He told me, that we need it and it is not senseles..

When I asked for a reason, he goes away.

I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a production server, where you wouldn't want downtime, you should have a rollback procedure. Even if that procedure is to just back the database up before the upgrade and restore from backup on failure.

You also imply that 'create procedure' will either work or not. This is true, but it doesn't mean the procedure will actually work. You can create a stored procedure (at least on SQL Server) that references a table that doesn't exist, and it will compile just fine.

Comment: Exactly!
That was my idea: The only true rollback is a backup and restore. The thing is, that that would mean a backup & restore of an 8GB database, that need 1-2 hours. And then my boss that: too expensive.

Answer (score 2):

There is some logic to what you're saying, but I could agree with your boss if the argument is tantamount to saying "we don't need to back up code that isn't working"

It's still somebody's expensive hours put into that, and the flaw may be a minor one. If it is conceivable that further updates could somehow make things even more wrong, then it is reasonable to request the ability to roll back to the less broken state.

Comment: I understand you, but I choose exact this SQL problem and nothing else because exectly here it's very clear:
When the create of the new procedure goes wrong, is something so very very failed or corrupt that a single procedure can't handle it.

Comment: Well not necessarily. A create procedure could fail because there's something wrong in the code of the procedure you're trying to create. Then you're stuck in a situation where your DELETE worked, but not your CREATE, and you're left with no procedure at all. In that case, a rollback would've at least had you up and running with the flawed SP

Answer (score 0):

Two wrongs don't make a right.

If the previous change to the SP had a rollback option then you wouldn't be in this situation. So even though you know that any rollback will go to a "bad" version. It should still be there.

The update you do here could break things a lot more than they currently are.

Answer (score 0):

> After a fast change from a colleague a stored procedure went wrong. (I think for the theory here is no more information requiered)

More information is required.

When changing a script, your colleague did two things:

1. He did (or did not) improve a stored procedure he fixed

   - He introduced a bug in this stored procedure

Whether you should or should not write this script, depends on these factors:

1. How significant the improvement was (if any)

   - How severe is the bug, and
   - How hard is to write this script.